# How can I call the actual constructor of a mocked mockito object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have code similar to this

```
class superClass {
    public String transform(String str) {
        //lots of logic including ajax calls
        return("Modified"+str);
    }
}

class baseClass extends superClass {
    private FetchData fetchData;
    baseClass(FetchData fetchData) {   
        this.fetchData = fetchData;
    }

    public String parse() {
        String str = fetchData.get();
        //some more logic to modify str
        return transform(str);
    }
}
```

and I am using mockito and junit to test it. I am mocking the `baseClass` and doing something like this

```
baseClass baseMock = Mockito.mock(baseClass.class);
Mockito.when(baseMock.parse()).thenCallRealMethod();
Mockito.when(baseMock.transform()).thenReturn("Something");
```

How can I inject the mock `fetchData`, as it is injected through the constructor?

Comment: you can't. You should either use reflection or expose setter in your base class.

Comment: What are you testing, `baseClass`? If so, I think you may be misunderstanding how testing. If you want to test `baseClass`, you wouldn't mock it. You'd mock anything it requires that isn't being tested. If you want to mock `FetchData`, you can easily do this by passing `baseClass` a different `FetchData` implementation (a mock). Also, your naming is a bit messed up. A superclass is a base class. Your `baseClass` should be `DerivedClass`, and your class names should always start with a capital letter. And please format your code properly, it's also not compilable as it currently is.

Comment: Hint: java class names go UpperCase. Always.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Mockito.spy` (http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy):

```
baseClass object = new baseClass(new FetchData());
baseClass spy = Mockito.spy(object);

Mockito.when(spy.parse()).thenCallRealMethod();
Mockito.when(spy.transform()).thenReturn("Something");
```

Comment: Awesome,that works thanks :) one question, how can i call the actual method with the do syntax because the

    `Mockito.when(spy.parse()).thenCallRealMethod(); `

calls the actual method, when that mock line executes, i want the method to be called only when i call spy.parse()

Comment: `Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(<objectInstance>).<method>();` However, please look at @GhostCat 's post below. What you appear to be trying to test doesn't make sense. Or, if you're just trying to test an abstract base class, perhaps don't use mockito. Make a subclass of it in your test class and use that.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is of a different nature: you created **hard to test** code. That is the thing with constructors: one has to be really careful about what they are doing.

The other thing is that you directly "ran" into "prefer composition over inheritance". It might be tempting to simply extend some other class to inherit some helpful behavior - but when you are doing that, you run exactly in such kind of problems!

My kinda non-answer: step back, and have a close look into your design if that is really the best solution. Probably you watch those [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) first to understand what I am talking about. If you have some experienced folks around, talk to them; and have them review your design.

Comment: It is a non-answer, reflecting your opinion about how code should be written. It would be better to post an answer to the question at hand, then go with your opinion, why not, instead of spamming Mockito answers with your video playlist.